# Searching for ranges in mongo

Tags: mongodb, optimization, database

What's the most efficient way to find data in Mongo, when the input data is a single value, and the collection data contains min/max ranges? E.g:

```
record = { min: number, max: number, payload }
```

Need to locate a record for a number that falls within the min/max range of the record. The ranges never intersect. There is no predictability about the size of the ranges.

The collection has ~6M records in it. If I unpack the ranges (have records for each value in range), I would be looking at about 4B records instead.

I've created the compound index of `{min:1,max:1}`, but attempt to search using:

```
db.block.find({min:{$lte:value},max:{$gte:value})
```

... takes anywhere from few to tens of seconds. Below are the output of `explain()` and `getIndexes()`. Is there any trick I can apply to make the search execute significantly faster?

```
NJmongo:PRIMARY> db.block.getIndexes()
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "mispot.block",
            "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "min" : 1,
                    "max" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "mispot.block",
            "name" : "min_1_max_1"
    }
] 


NJmongo:PRIMARY> db.block.find({max:{$gte:1135194602},min:{$lte:1135194602}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor min_1_max_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1199049,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1199050,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2398098,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 7534,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 5060,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "min" : [
                    [
                            -1.7976931348623157e+308,
                            1135194602
                    ]
            ],
            "max" : [
                    [
                            1135194602,
                            1.7976931348623157e+308
                    ]
            ]
    },
    "server" : "ccc:27017"
}
```

Comment: that's a long time - how much RAM do you have?  What version of MongoDB is this?  And can you run mongostat and capture its output while the query is running?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky as Leopd stated correctly, it's not really unexpected, the database has to search through a lot of records (look at the explain output). Unless MongoDB supports geometric indexes, this is just the fact of life, or I have to use some trick (evaluating his now) :)

Comment: It does support 2d indexes but their semantic meaning is specifically for geo. still it might work for you if you come up with some clever application.

Comment: 2d indexes can be very effectively used for overlapping ranges queries - it doesn't have to be actual coordinates, just start,end pairs (for example)

Comment: I would need a 1d index in this case :) Using LineSegment (I can repurpose a 2d for that, locking down 2nd coord to 0). I would then call geoNear() to find the "closest" (distance 0) segment to my point. @AsyaKamsky let me know if you want me to just try that for kicks.

Comment: I think it should work! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ranges of your `block` records never overlap, then you can accomplish this much faster with:

```
db.block.find({min:{$lte:value}}).sort({min:-1}).limit(1)
```

This query will return almost instantly since it can find the record with a simple lookup in the index.

The query you are running is slow because the two clauses each match on millions of records that must be merged.  In fact, I think your query would run faster (maybe much faster) with separate indexes on `min` and `max` since the `max` part of your compound index can only be used for a given `min` -- not to search for documents with a specific `max`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. The only thing I need to add - is to check the value of `max` if an element was found (as there are holes in the ranges). Thank you!

Comment: except that you are incorrect about why the query is slow - there is no two clauses that return millions that will be merged.  The issue is that the leading part of the index is used with an inequality which doesn't provide much selectivity.

Comment: @Asya agree that the biggest problem is no usable index on `max` so it has to scan the collection.  But I think for that strategy to really be efficient mongo would have to support index intersection which it doesn't yet: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3071